# How to set masks IDs in exported SVG?

Tags: svg, mask, figma

Masks exported in SVG have a default ID of "mask0" `<mask id="mask0" ...>`.  I tried changing the mask layer name, but it doesn't influence the ID in the exported SVG.

How do I declare masks IDs in exported SVGs?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm not a Figma user, but you might want to check if there is a built in XML editor like in Inkscape.  If not, then you could just edit the XML (the SVG file) in a text editor.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi! Sorry, I don't see it as an option. Changing SVG manually seems to me like clear opportunity for mistakes. As well as unnecessary time spent in the hand-off process. It is an obvious workaround, but just that. Thanks tho!